# Check if value is in array in ruby

Tags: ruby

So far I have:

```
ship = arr.include?(1)
```

But it always shows up as false even though I know there is a 1 in the array. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the array include integer `1` or string `"1"`?

Comment: When you ask a question, it helps if you provide an example input, in this case, an array demonstrating what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array#include?` is the method you're looking for.

```
[1,2,3,4,54,5].include?(1)
=> true
```

If it returns false on you it's because the item you're looking for is not there. Is the `1` you are looking for a number or a string?

In that case it will return false

```
["1",2,3,4,54,5].include?(1)
=> false
```

The array provided in the comments was not a one-dimensional array but a 2d array.

You can flatten the arrays and then check for the inclusion of the value like this

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 3],[0, 0, 1]].flatten.include?(1)
=> true
```

Or use `any?` along with `include?` like so

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 3],[0, 0, 1]].any? { |ary| ary.include?(1) }
=> true
```

Comment: The array contains integers but I have also tried it with "!" in case it was being stored as a string and that didn't work either.
Does the fact it's a 2d array change anything?

Comment: @JohnSumner Please post `puts arr.inspect` The `.include?()` will work if the value is present.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0]]

is what is included in the array

Comment: @JohnSumner That isn't one simple array, it is a multidimensional array. You need to determine if any _sub-array_ `.include?(1)`.

Comment: You could `.flatten` it as in `arr.flatten.include?(1)` to combine them all into a 1D array.